SQLite3 DB to front end in flask just creates empty tags for each row
I've read the docs and looked at 2 different tutorials all do it the same way but my front end renders with empty tags but it creates a tag for the expect items in the database.
The desired behaviour is that there is a p tag for each row in the feedback column of the database.
I have a SQLite3 db, that has data in it, table created with this query:
CREATE TABLE feedback(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,feedback TEXT NOT NULL);
This function gets all the data from the database
def listFeedback():
    print("hello")
    con = sql.connect("databaseFiles/database.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    data = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM feedback').fetchall()
    con.close()
    return data

This renders the tempate
return render_template('/sucess.html', state=True, posts=listFeedback())
This is in the template
  {% for post in posts %}
      <div class='post'>
          <p>{{ post['feedback'] }}</p>
      </div>
  {% endfor %}

If I have 6x items in the DB the front will have 6x empty p tags even though the feedback column has text content.
post.feedback has same effect but just using post will fill the P tag with all columns from each row when I just want the one row.

Have you tried to print your post list for starters…?

Yes, Post on its own will sucesfully create a P tag for each row in the database correctly populated.

What does that mean, “Post on its own”?

I’m saying: look at your data! print what listFeedback() returns exactly to get some first hand information. Is it actually the data you expect? Is it actually in the format you expect? Is it actually in the format your template expects to receive?

Try to use {{ post.feedback }}
Result will:
  {% for post in posts %}
      <div class='post'>
          <p>{{ post.feedback }}</p>
      </div>
  {% endfor %}


Does exactly the same just creates an empty p tag for each item in the database

how i see in post you have feedback objects. Can you show fieldnames in feedback?You have a feedback field in feedback model?

Database has a feedback column. When I do just post it prints the whole row in parenthesis. I want the feedback column only.

Just add <p>{{ post[1] }}</p>, because it returns list of tuples.
